# Помогите понять, почему код работает не так, как должен

Tags: c++

Даные целые числа a1...a(n), действительная квадратная матрица порядка n.
Заменить нулями в матрице те элементы с четной суммой индексов, для которых имеются равные среди a1...a(n)
Вот пример моего кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
   int n;
   cout << "Введите размерность матрицы: ";
   cin >> n;
   int *B = new int[n];
   for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       cout << "Введите " << i << " число: ";
       cin >> B[i];
   }
   float **A = new float*[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = new float [n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
           cout << "Введите элемент массива с индексом " << i << ',' << j << ": ";
           cin >> A[i][j];
       }
   }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
           for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
           {
               if ((i+j)%2==0 and B[k] == A[i][j])
               {
                   A[i][j] = 0;
               }
           }
       }
   }
cout << "Выведем измененную матрицу:\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
           cout << A[i][j] << ' ';
       }
       cout << '\n';
   }
}
```

Не могу понять, почему некоторые элементы матрицы программа просто не хочет менять и оставляет прежними.

Comment: Приведите пример. Вроде работает код.

Comment: Пример нужен. На котором по вашему неправильно работает. Причем желательно пример с выводом из программы. Т.е. перед началом изменений сделайте вывод как матрицы A так и массива B - возможно уже это вам поможет отладить самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо всем, я разобрался, оказывается в самом первом цикле for нужно было начинать с нуля, а не с единицы, из-за этого некоторые числа он просто пропускал, так как индексы разные были

Comment: Так в приведенном коде циклы с нуля начинались.

Comment: Самый первый цикл, когда я добавляю элементы в массив B, начинается с единицы)

Comment: Да, именно в этом и была проблема: массивы начинаются с нулевого элемента, а последний индекс на 1 меньше количества элементов, из-за чего код ещё и залезал за пределы выделенной ему памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Код вроде работает, не нашел ошибок.
Немного оптимизации:
Циклы ввода и обработки можно совместить. Т.е. после ввода элемента сразу проверять на условия замены.
И проверку немного перекомпоновать, чтобы не делать лишних проходов по массиву `B[]` - сначала проверять на четность сумму индексов, а только потом искать элемент в массиве `B[]`. Также можно проверять, не является ли введенное число `0` - в данном случае можно не выполнять дальше проверку.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> A[i][j];
            if ( (i+j)%2 == 0 )
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                    if ( B[k] == A[i][j] )
                        A[i][j] = 0;
        }
```